# "File not found" error when compiling c programs in ubuntu

Tags: c, ubuntu

I just installed CodeBlocks IDE in UBUNTU 14 SO and created a new project. When trying to compile my program, even though there is no syntax error the message in the terminal is `sh: 1: /home/Documents/OMP/bin/Debug/OMP: not found`

I used the run button on CodeBlocks to compile it. Is it possible to compile programs in this way or maybe I should write some code in the terminal to compile it? How can I compile this?

Comment: Try JetBrain's C++ IDE instead - CLion: https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try compiling with gcc via terminal first it's much more simpler if It's a basic program.
Open the terminal ctrl+alt+t 
The run

> gcc myfile.c -o NameOfOutput
>
> gcc -o NameOfOutput myfile.c

Then to run the program:

> ./NameOfOutput

Lets test this program via Terminal

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void){

    printf("Hello Terminal\n");
    return 0;

}
```

[image]

Note the cd command lets you move from directory to the desired one. 
 Edit:
I would personally use netbeans as it's much more simple from my point of view for unix systems. Note that you need java for netbeans here are the  commands to install Java via terminal

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: It says no such file or directory.I replaced "pro.c" with the name of my file "main.c"

Comment: Make sure you are in the directory where this file is saved suppose you saved it in the Desktop. You would have to open terminal and use the cd Desktop/ command

Comment: Ok thanks! But isn't it easier to run the codes from the run button in IDE?Is it possible?

Comment: Yeah, but remember that in most cases you have to create a proyect and what not. And if you need to test something quickly its a drag

Comment: Once again I would recommend netbeans for development in C but that's a personal opinion. If the answer helped out consider making is the best answer, thanks!!!